# Write an application called Tail, that prints the last k strings found on the standard input (assuming the standard input has k or more strings)

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, variable-assignment

The code below is what I've come up with so far for my assignment listed above. How do I print the last word of a text file in java using java.util. My biggest confusion is what to do after you check each sting on a txt file and how you get the last word in the file.

```
    import java.util.*;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.IOException;

    public class Tail {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // open a text file for reading
        String filename = new String("hithere.txt");
        Scanner sc;
        try {

            int wordnumber = 0;

            sc = new Scanner(new File("tinytinyTale.txt"));
            while (sc.hasNext() ) {
                String s = sc.next();
                System.out.println(s.lastIndexOf(" "));  
            }
            sc.close();


            System.out.println(s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(" ")+1)) ;


        } 


        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The overall plan for such a program is to read the file by words, keeping only the last 'k' words.  When you've finished reading the file, the words you have will be the last 'k'.

(I'm assuming "strings" in the title means "words", since you then use the words in the body of the question.  But the principle remains unchanged if "strings" means "lines")

In pseudocode:

```
lastWords = list of size k, initially empty

while there is a next word to read:
     w = next word from file
     if lastWords is full (has k entries already):
          discard oldest entry from lastWords
     add w to lastWords list

print out contents of lastWords
```

Writing that in Java is an exercise for you to do.